# How to disable users to view Other pages

Tags: plugins, menus, pages, admin-bar

I have a membership website where my users can create their own page. I use below snippets in function.php to remove the options of published, trash etc. of other users and only show "mine".

```
/**
 * Remove the 'all', 'publish', 'future', 'sticky', 'draft', 'pending', 'trash' 
 * views for non-admins
 */
add_filter( 'views_edit-page', function( $views )
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return $views;

    $remove_views = [ 'all','publish','future','sticky','draft','pending','trash' ];

    foreach( (array) $remove_views as $view )
    {
        if( isset( $views[$view] ) )
            unset( $views[$view] );
    }
    return $views;
} );
```

It is working fine. When a user create a page, it is showing only the "mine" option.

But When a new user 1st time come to create a page (they have not created any page); they still can view the "All" options where all the published page (of other users) are shown. Also when they delete his all "mine" pages, they can view the "All" option.

So how to stop users to see the "all" option when they 1st time come to create a page or delete all their pages?

Comment: Modify the [WP_Query based on author](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) and use [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action to list only current user's posts.

Comment: Thank you for help. But actually I do not know that much coding. I just found those codes from a answer of stackexchange & used it. Can you help me with any such function.php snippet codes which I can use.

Comment: @MaxYudin you should write an answer from that comment

Comment: @Deb any answer you get on this site will be technical, if you're looking for a copy paste solution, then this isn't the place, if the code answers the question but doesn't do exactly what's necessary, e.g. markup is different, you'll need to be able to change it yourself

Comment: @TomJNowell, As a new member, I understand your concern. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: @TomJNowell, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_current_author_posts');

function my_current_author_posts( $query )
{
    global $pagenow;

    // Check if you are on the right Admin page, do nothing if not
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || ! isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || 'page' != $_GET['post_type'] || ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // get current user Object
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // check user capabilities
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_pages' ) ) {

        // remove views for pages, see the function below
        add_action( 'views_edit-page', 'my_remove_views' );

        // set WP_Query 'Author' parameter
        $query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
    }

    return $query;
}

// function to remove views
function my_remove_views( $views )
{

    $views_to_remove = array(
        'all',
        'publish',
        'future',
        'sticky',
        'draft',
        'pending',
        'trash',
    );

    foreach ( $views_to_remove as $view_to_remove ) {
        unset( $views[$view_to_remove] );
    }

    return $views;
}
```

Comment: I used, but not worked. New users can still view pages from other authors. Anyway thanks for giving your time & writing this codes.

Comment: Check users' capabilities. Possibly, they can `edit_others_posts`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've copied and changed my working code but forgot to change `edit_others_posts` to `edit_others_pages`. Fixed.

Comment: I used, but still users can view other pages. Check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/ica06m

When some user have not created any page or delete all their page, they can view pages of other authors.

Comment: Check fixed `if` statement: `'page' != $query->post_type` changed to `! isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || 'page' != $_GET['post_type']`. I personally have different solution working with CPTs, but this shoud work too.

Comment: Thank you very very much @MaxYudin , it is working great. Thank you again. You are awesome.

Comment: If so, please [accept the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).